# Javascript: compare two dates inside an if

Tags: javascript

The function card should return the card of a certain concert.
But only if the concert's date match the date selected with the datepicker's function. So if I choose the date 06/22/2018 I should see the concert card because the date is the same. But right now it doesn't work because the line:

```
if(document.getElementById("datepicker").value == this.date)
```

is picking the value of the input at the top, which is undefined, so it doesn't show anything. So I think I have first to call the function datepicker(),but I don't know how to do.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/></div>
<div id="corpo1"></div>


$(function() 
{
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonText: "Select date",
      buttonImage: "https://i.imgur.com/cvkNy5G.png"
   });
});


function Concert(id, name, date, price)
{
   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
   this.date = date;
   this.price = price;

   this.card = function()
    {
       if(document.getElementById("datepicker").value == this.date)
       return "<span class='concert'>"+this.name+" "+this.date+"</span>";

    }
}

var concerti = [ new Concert(1,"The Fame Ball","06/22/2018",50) ];

function showcard(f)
{
        var ris = "";
        for(var i in concerti) 
        {
            ris+=concerti[i].card();
        }
        document.getElementById('corpo1').innerHTML=ris;
}
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: So my initial thoughts on this is it's likely a formatting issue i.e. the `datepicker` plugin is formatting the date differently to the hard-coded date format? Regardless, if you want reliable date comparisons then use actual dates instances (numerical) and not strings...

Comment: `.value` is a string.

Comment: Try to to add this
console.log(document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
console.log(this.date);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6gub2smo/2/
The key change is the following:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonText: "Select date",
  buttonImage: "https://i.imgur.com/cvkNy5G.png",
  onSelect: showcard
});
```

jQuery UI recommends using the `onSelect` event. Documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

> Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker is selected.
>   The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker
>   instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Comment: Thaks!! :) It works now. Amazing how just one line can change everything. Thaks again

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think you're having that your `showcard` code isn't being run, at least not at the right time. Adding the following to your Javascript should fix the issue.

```
$("#datepicker").change(showcard);
```

It will cause the showcard function to be run when the user selects a new date, when the text of the textbox is changed. The issue you might be having with "undefined" showing up if you don't select the date of the Concert is because the showcard function returns nothing (turned into "undefined") if the dates don't match. You can fix this by adding `return "";` to the end of the function to force it to return an empty string and have nothing show up.